# Enviar y mostrar contenido en un modal

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy intentando mostrar el contenido de un php en un modal mediante un js pero no aparece nada
Tengo el siguiente JS que lo que intenta hacer es enviar la variable AJAX hacia el PHP y el resultado de este seria mostrado en el modal

```
$.ajax({
  url: "table.php",
  data: {AJAX: table},
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data)
  {
    $('#modal').show();
    $('#modal-body').show().html(data);
  }
});
```

El contenido del PHP es el siguiente:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['AJAX'])) {
        $name = $_POST['AJAX'];
    }
    echo $name;
    ?>
```

El contenido del modal es el siguiente:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">                
        <!-- load content table.php -->         
        </div> 
</div>
```

Que me esta fallando y que debería de realizar para solucionarlo?
gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría ser porque tienes
$('#modal-body').show().html(data);
pero # se usa para id y tú tienes modal-body en el class

puedes hacer:`$('.modal-body').show().html(data);`

o también:
 `<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">`

con una de las dos debería funcionar

Comment: perfecto!! muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "table.php",
  data: {AJAX: table},
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data)
  {        
    $('#modal-body').html(data);
    $('#modal').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: me ha ido mejor el comentario anterior. Gracias igualmente!